# Action menu items text color when long clicking tasks/recents button of the device

Tags: android

I have successfully changed the text color of my menu item when clicking on the top right triple colon.

[image]

This was at first white text too but I managed to change it using the toolbar theme.
But it occurs differently when long clicking the tasks button of the devices. It appears in bottom plus my menu item is white.

[image]

I did lots of textColor changing on my base theme but all did not work

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme without actionbar. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Set color of the ToolBar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Set color of the StatusBar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!-- Set color of the Accent -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.Normal" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Set color of the ToolBar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Set color of the StatusBar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!-- Set color of the Accent -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
</style>

<!-- App theme no action bar -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<!-- Toolbar Theme -->
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
</style>

<!-- App alert dialog theme -->
<style name="AppTheme.AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- App Design Tab Layout -->
<style name="AppTheme.SampleTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">@dimen/tabIndicatorHeight</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>


<!-- Tab Text Appearance -->
<style name="AppTheme.SampleTabLayout.TextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>

<!-- TabLayout -->
<style name="AppTheme.TabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">@dimen/tabIndicatorHeight</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>

<!-- Tab Text Appearance -->
<style name="AppTheme.TabLayout.TextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<!-- Tab Text Appearance -->
<style name="AppTheme.KenzaiProgressBar.Indeterminate" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/kenzai_animated_image_load</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/kenzai_progressbar_width_and_height</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/kenzai_progressbar_width_and_height</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
</style>
```

How do I fix this?

**Edit:**
Searching for a clear definition of the tasks/recents button of the device, Found this https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32697/what-is-the-offical-name-of-the-third-on-screen-button

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it.. it was very dependent to textColorSecondary of the ToolbarTheme
so to change the text color without changing the drawer arrow color of white just do

```
<!-- Toolbar Theme -->
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```